# libpq Postgres PQexecParams 2 hours timeout

Tags: postgresql, timeout, libpq

I am using libpq v9.6.8 for my Application (running 24/7), which inserts data into the postgres database. I also run [PQexecParams](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-exec.html) to get the table columns. But randomly (sometimes just once a week, but then twice a weekend) this blocking `PQexecParams` call somehow returns after about 2 hours. Within these two hours my application just hangs... The inserts are done via async `PQsendQueryParams`.

Is there a way to configure the timeout for `PQexecParams` (as I cannot find any appropriate timeout settings in the lib maybe on the postgres server)? Is there a better way to perform the select synchronous?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The two hours suggest TCP keepalive kicking in and determining that the connection has gone bad.

You can set the [`keepalives_idle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) connection parameter so that the timeout happens earlier and you are not stalled for two hours.

But you probably also want to know what aborts the network connection. Your first look should be at the PostgreSQL server log; you should see an error message that matches the one on the client side. Probably a network component is at fault – look for firewalls in particular.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with keepalives_idle I will run a test with that option. As I do not have access to the postgres server config, I cannot change the loglevel and with the current level I do not see any errors..

Comment: sadly I do have to point out that I had the same error again, but this time after 2hours nothing happened, and after 6hours the Call still blocked the application. I set keepalives_idle to 5... any more advices?

Comment: Perhaps it is not a network issue, but a lock. You write about concurrent inserts: does your `PQexecParams` only select or also modify data? Then it might be a good idea to look at `pg_locks` and set `log_lock_waits = on`. At any rate, try to find out that the backend process for this session is doing. Is it still there? Is it consuming CPU or not? Does it show activity when you attach `strace` to it?